How to bake NLA to keyframes
New to blender coming from Maya. I have some action strips on a character, and I'd like to bake down all the animation into key frames so that I can start hand animating on top of it.  I tried following this Youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFURoPlZJxs, but after it baked, no key frames were created in the graph editor, and when I deleted the action strips, the animation also was removed.  
I also see warnings like this in the console if it's of any insight:
"WARN (bke.anim_sys): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v350\blender.git\source\blender\blenkernel\intern\anim_sys.c:4192 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["CTR_neck_FK.004"].custom_shape_scale[0]"
Any help baking to key frames would be greatly appreciated.

tbh i would search for "better" tutorials on yt - and there are tons of them - with (!) spoken explanation. Because you will learn a lot more and by voice you can learn much quicker than by reading and (!) simultaneously watching what he is doing.

Select the armature, select the strips, 3D View > Object > Animation > Bake, choose the Pose option insead of Object, click OK, it has created a new action in the Dope Sheet, if it doesn't work please share your file (only keep the armature)
